# Отображение предыдущего окна при нажатии на кнопку "назад"

Tags: javascript, html

**Имеется конфигурация страницы:** меню и блок с текстом, зависящий от нажатой копки меню.

**Параметры URL:** зависят от нажатой в меню кнопки, задаются с помощью скрипта, прилепленного к каждой кнопке.

**Проблема:** при нажатии браузерной кнопки ***назад***  URL меняется, а вот блок - нет.

Есть ли какой-то обработчик для кнопки назад? 
Какой выход из ситуации может быть? 
Только начинаю разбираться в вебе, возможно есть более адкватные варианты создания параметров  для URL?

UPD: создание url выглядит так:

```
    function createUrl(x) {
    var myUrl = "";
    myUrl = "?button=" + x.id;
    history.pushState(null, null, myUrl )

}
```

Отображение блока так:

```
function checkMenuButton(x) {
    str=x.id+"Window";

    str=document.getElementById(str);

    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("textWindow");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].style.display="none";
    }

    if(str!=null) {
        str.style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть сам код, чтобы было легче понять суть самой проблемы, и если у вас меняются параметры в URL после нажатия кнопки "назад", то возможно проблема в обработчике события смены URL или что-то подобное

Comment: 4к строк говнокода очень  стыдно показывать).  Тот факт, что юрл меняется меня более чем устраивает. То бишь на предыдущую кнопку вроде как "кликнули"...

Comment: @Isin Min, функция запускается при загрузке страницы? 
если я правильно понял, то можно же проверить url окна и вставить нужный текст в блок?

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку. Т.к страница по сути-то одна, только с разными всплывающими текстовыми блоками.

Comment: @Isin Min,создайте функцию, которая будет запускаться при загрузке страницы. Функция должна брать url и в зависимости от него показывать нужный блок

Comment: При нажатии кнопки назад произойдет перезагрузка страницы?

Comment: @Isin Min, кстати тоже об этом задумался)
нашел такое собитие: window.onhashchange = function(){} - дальше по стандарту. Написанно что запускается при изменении хэша окна. если правда работает то функцию прямо в нём запускать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, при `history.pushState` первым параметром передавайте объект, содержащий в себе новый `url`.

Тогда обработчик для кнопки назад можно получить так:

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    // здесь из объекта event.state можете получить текущий url и отобразить актуальный текст
};
```